# Flutter dart sdk version null safety error

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, dependencies

I am not able to add any more dependencies because of null safety error, it says my dart sdk is not correct, please have a look:
[image]

I have tried flutter clean and everything but its not helping. And also my material.dart file is also showing as not identified:
[image]

Please help me.

Here is my pubscpec.yaml file:
[image]

Comment: can you please share your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Please, don't share pictures of text. Just share the text itself. Pictures can't be searched. People have told you this before, at other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pubspec.yaml` file have set a requirement for the the Dart SDK to be between 2.0 and less than 3.0. The issue here is that Dart 3.0 removed support for null-safety which got introduced with Dart 2.12.

So if you are using Dart 3.0, you can only work on projects which have a minimum version requirement of Dart 2.12.

I am a bit concerned that your project have Dart 2.0.0 as minimum requirement since that could indicate it is very old and you might get into other problems. You would at least need to update the project to support Dart null-safety: https://dart.dev/null-safety

But to fix your current issue, you need to open your `pubspec.yaml` file and change your supported SDK to e.g.:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: "^3.0.0"
```

This is the same as saying `>=3.0.0 <4.0.0`. This will also give access to all the other features introduced with Dart 3.0.

Comment: I have tried but still the same error earlier my code was working but after installing a dependency named flutter_launcher_icons my whole code messed up and this error is showing and now my flutter clean, dart pub get, flutter pub get nothing is working

Comment: Post your `pubspec.yaml` in your question as Mihir also suggests.

Comment: done sharing pubspec.yaml file

Comment: @KapilSarania You did not share the full file! We need to see the dependency section. Also, share it as text instead of screenshots!